# eli5.permutation_importance get_score_importances crashes Google Colab session

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, eli5

I came across `eli5.permutation_importance` `get_score_importances` from the following article: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-feature-importances-for-blackbox-models-c418b694659d; here is the [documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/permutation_importance.html).

When I try to use `get_score_importances` on my neural network my RAM increases and my session crashes in Google Colab. The shape of `x_test` is `(34463, 2355)`.

Here is my NN Model

```
NN_model = Sequential()
NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = 
x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))

# Compile the network :
NN_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['mean_absolute_error'])
NN_model.summary()

#Define a checkpoint callback
checkpoint_name = 'Weights-{epoch:03d}--{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5' 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 
1, save_best_only = True, 
mode ='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

#train a neural network model
NN_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=32, validation_split = 
 0.2, 
callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Here's the code I use to run get_score_importances

```
import numpy as np
from eli5.permutation_importance import get_score_importances

import numpy as np
y_array = np.array(y_test)
x_array = np.array(x_test)

#score function
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
def score(X, y):
    predictions = NN_model.predict(X)
    return mean_absolute_error(y , predictions)

# This function takes only numpy arrays as inputs
#The following line crashes the session
base_score, score_decreases = get_score_importances(score,x_array, y_array)
#The following line never gets run
feature_importances = np.mean(score_decreases, axis=0)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that's making Google Colab crash? I'm running 8GB of RAM with Intel Core i7 5500U CPU at 2.4 GHZ, Windows 64 bit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google collab uses free server hardware by default, with the size of those arrays you're probably running out of memory. Try installing a local python+tf/keras runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My understanding is Google Colab offers 12GB of RAM whereas I have 8GB on my laptop. So running it on my system would be a downgrade.